# How to check child component is dirty in CanDeactivateGuard when i have mutiple form tags?

Tags: angular

I am using template driven form. I have a parent component

parent.component.html

```
<tab>
  <form>
     <input></input>
     <button></button>
   </form>
<tab>
   <form>
          <child-component 1></child-component 1>
    </form>
</tab>


<tab>
   <form>
          <child-component 2></child-component 2>
    </form>
</tab>


<tab>
   <form>
          <child-component 3></child-component 3>
    </form>
</tab>
```

In CanDeactivateGuard, how can I check the child component is dirty?
And also how to prevent closing the browser  when the form is dirty? (I have multiple form tags)

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions here:

1) "how can I check the child component is dirty"

You can do it in many ways, the simples one that I can think about right is to:

- use `ViewChild` for each child
- each child has some method like `isDirty`
- you call Child's `isDirty` methods in parent to check if they are dirty

2) "And also how to prevent closing the browser when the form is dirty"

Answer for 2:
You can't. What you can do is prevent destroying the component inside the application, so, for example, if user want's to go from 'add customer' screen to 'customer list' screen and the form is dirty, then something will happend.

To achive this:

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  (...)
  }, {
    path: 'path-to-parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
  }, {
  (...)
}]
```

some guard file, like **can-deactivate.guard.ts**

```
export interface GuardedComponent {
  canDeactivate: (nextStateUrl?: string) => Observable<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<GuardedComponent> {

  constructor() {}

  public canDeactivate(
    component: GuardedComponent,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate(nextState.url);
  }
}
```

and then in your **parent.component.ts**

```
  public canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    // code which will decide if component can be deactivated
  }
```